# How to prevent double decimals in a C# calculator

Tags: c#, calculator, number-formatting

I'm developing a calculator in C# and I have a button that inserts a decimal point into the number. I ran into a problem where it allows the user to insert multiple decimal points into the interface, which threw everything off. I cooked up this little statement:

```
if ((number % 1) > 0)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "";
}
else
{
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + ".";
}
```

Except it doesn't do anything! Will someone please show me a way to only allow one decimal point by fixing this statement?

Comment: Not sure why you would use the modulo operator here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

Comment: Checking if text already contains "." would make more sense... Please show value of `number` and what is you expectation for different values (like for `number = -3.5`).

Comment: @LeeTaylor a decimal number % 1 will give you the decimal part. 1.25 % 1 = 0.25.

Answer (score 5):

```
onButtonToInsertDecimalClick

    if richTextBox1.Text.Contains(".")
        return;

    else
        ... rest of code
```

Wouldn't this (pseudocode) work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Double.TryParse directly?

```
if(Double.TryParse(richTextBox1.Text, myDoubleValue) == false)
    richTextBox1.Text = lastGoodValue;
else
    lastGoodValue = richTextBox1.Text;
```

this will also, via TryParse, give your actual double variable the proper result. As long as this occurs every time richTextBox1.Text changes, the correction code should also cause the double value to remain good, since it'll trigger when Text is reverted to lastGoodValue.